# Visual Studio SQL Debug Window

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I remember a window in Visual Studio 2010 where I could see all of the sql calls made on runtime in my ASP.NET MVC project. I don't remember the window name and I cannot find it. Does anybody know/remember this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to the [IntelliTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915.aspx) window?

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's the one! Thank you